# How to show edit button only for a record and save data to database from edit form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am displaying all the records from db in the form of HTML table along with edit button. On, click of edit button it redirects to edit view which will display the additional columns.

Here, I was showing save button in edit form for all the rows/records. Is there a way to prevent so that I can just show to the one I selected in index form.

Also, after updating the fields how do I save the record and redirect to index view.

Please find the code snippets below:

**metrics_controller.rb:**

```
class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @metricAll = Metric.all
  end

  def show
    @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
    @metricAll = Metric.all
  end

  def create
    @metric = Metric.new(post_params)
    if(@metric.save)
      redirect_to @metric
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
    if(@metric.update_attributes(post_params))
      redirect_to @metric
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private def post_params
    params.require(:metric).permit(:Metric, :WI, :Value, :UT, :Score, :IsValid, :UserName, :Comments)
  end
end
```

**edit.html.rb:**

```
<%= form_for :metrics_controller, url: metric_path(@metric), method: :patch do |f| %>
  <table id="metrics">
    <thead>
    <tr id="AllMetricColumnNames">
      <th id="Metric"><div>Metric</th>
      <th id="WI">WI</th>
      <th id="Value">Value</th>
      <th id="UT">UT</th>
      <th id="Score">Score</th>
      <th id="IsValid">IsValid</th>
      <th id="UserName">UserName</th>
      <th id="Comments">Comments</th>
      <th id="EditColumn">Edit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <% @metricAll.each do |data| %>
      <tr id="AllMetricValues">
        <td id="Value"><%= data.Metric %></td>
        <td id="WI"><%= data.WI %></td>
        <td id="Value"><%= data.Value %></td>
        <td id="UT"><%= data.UT %></td>
        <td id="Score"><%= data.Score %></td>
        <td><%= f.select :IsValid, options_for_select(['True', 'False']), :include_blank => true, :class => 'chosen-select', :required => true, value: data.IsValid  %></td>
        <td id="UserName"><%= data.UserName %></td>
        <td id="Comments"><%= f.text_field :Comments, value: data.Comments %></td>
        <td id="SaveButton"><%= f.submit "Save" %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `form` for each `metric`:

```
<table id="metrics">
  <thead>
  <tr id="AllMetricColumnNames">
    <th id="Metric"><div>Metric</th>
    <th id="WI">WI</th>
    <th id="Value">Value</th>
    <th id="UT">UT</th>
    <th id="Score">Score</th>
    <th id="IsValid">IsValid</th>
    <th id="UserName">UserName</th>
    <th id="Comments">Comments</th>
    <th id="EditColumn">Edit</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @metricAll.each do |data| %>
    <%= form_for :metrics_controller, url: metric_path(data), method: :patch do |f| %>
      <tr id="AllMetricValues">
        <td id="Value"><%= data.Metric %></td>
        <td id="WI"><%= data.WI %></td>
        <td id="Value"><%= data.Value %></td>
        <td id="UT"><%= data.UT %></td>
        <td id="Score"><%= data.Score %></td>
        <td><%= f.select :IsValid, options_for_select(['True', 'False']), :include_blank => true, :class => 'chosen-select', :required => true, value: data.IsValid  %></td>
        <td id="UserName"><%= data.UserName %></td>
        <td id="Comments"><%= f.text_field :Comments, value: data.Comments %></td>
        <td id="SaveButton"><%= f.submit "Save" %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: still having the same issue

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash above must work , please what error report you for above changes or controller action goes in processing.

Comment: I am still able to see save button for all the records. And upon saving the record, I get the following error:

ActionController::ParameterMissing in MetricsController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: metric

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"iF1pEruUPuX9uRSv5ubNpvBRXNOrbfcV+E9iadp7JmPYjIQpfV955E3Nx3TMMtFvNLH2SUVUwcseZnsylbeuaw==",
 "metrics_controller"=>{"IsValid"=>"", "Comments"=>"Valid"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"Metric1"}

Comment: Able to sort it out. I was iterating on all the records instead of a specific record.
Updated the code to show the data only for a single record and the issue is now resolved.